# Trying to write a javascript function that counts to the number inputted

Tags: javascript

Trying to take  an  integer and have it return  as a
string  with    the integers    from    1   to  the number  passed.
Trying to use   a   loop to return the string but not sure how!

Example of how I want it to look:

```
count(5)    =>  1,  2,  3,  4,  5
count(3)    =>  1,  2,  3
```

Not really sure where to even start

Comment: Post the code you have. A loop would be a correct first start. Then you just have to append to a string and return that string. If you struggle with that you may want to spend some more time reading a JavaScript book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ .

Comment: Did you try defining a function?  Did you try using a for loop?

Comment: I would take a look into string concatentation and [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Thanks for the help I had no clue where to really even start!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it with a recursive function. Keep concatenating the numbers until it reaches 1.

```
var sequence = function(num){
    if(num === 1) return '1';
    return sequence(num - 1) + ', ' + num;
}
```

Or just:

```
var sequence = (num) => num === 1 ? '1' : sequence(num - 1) + ', ' + num;
```

Comment: You'll definitely pass his exam :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) to iterate the number of times that you pass in. Then, you need an [if-statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) to handle the comma (since you don't want a comma at the end of the string).

```
function count(num) {
  var s = "";
  for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    s += i;

    if (i < (num)) {
      s += ', ';
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cokiliveme/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function count(n) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        arr.push(i.toString());
    }
    return arr.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you perform string concatenation on an array and a number?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You are doing `[] + 1`. Why? If you want to add to the array, it should be `[].push(i)`. If you want to perform string concatenation then you don't need an array.

Comment: I am doing **`+=`** `"1"`

Comment: That's what I am saying. And it's wrong. Why would one ever do that? Again: You are concatenating an **empty array** to a string / number. `[] + 1` is essentially the  same as `"" + 1`.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting behavior. Fixed.

Comment: You can also do `return arr.join(",");`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-recursive solution:

```
var sequence = num => new Array(num).fill(0).map((e, i) => i + 1).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a goofy way to do it

```
function count(i)
{
    while (i--) {
        out = (i + 1) + "," + this.out;
    }
    return (out + ((delete out) && "")).replace(",undefined", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly **the** most ridiculous way, defining an iterator:

```
"use strict";

function count ( i ) {
  let n = 0;
  let I = {};
  I[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
     return { next: function() { return (n > i) ? {done:true}
                                                : {done:false, value:n++} } } };
  let s = "";
  let c = "";
  for ( let i of I ) {
      s += c + i;
      c = ", "
  }
  return s;
}


let s = count(3);
console.log(s);
```